# displaying charts in browser while keeping data safe

Tags: security, actionscript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have recently been exploring the different options for displaying charts in a browser.

I have tried using the `d3js` library, google charts, java applets and actionscript(Flash).

My research shows that people are moving away from flash and java. This makes `d3js` an attractive option. Though I see the value in using `d3js` I have an issue:

**Simply right click and 'view source' and one can see the raw data going in to the chart.**

This is why I considered flash and java since the source can not be seen.

On the other hand I am hearing people say that flash has security exploits.

Am I missing something?

So my question is:

**How do I use `d3.js` while keeping my data safe?**

I am relatively new to data visualization and I will appreciate any responses.

Thank You.

Comment: If you're showing the data to the user, how do you expect the user not to get it? Please explain your requirements and concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for a method of encoding the data so it is not plain text. However, an experienced JavaScript programmer can decode the data without issue. The same goes for flash and java also. Anything on the front end exposes your data. There are backend libraries for displaying charts I know for a fact php has lots of them, Other languages should have them too. A backend solution would make it so the only way to get your data is to pull it from the image either manually or with line detection.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of learning more about the php chart displaying backends? cheers!

Comment: [link](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) pchart  and [link](http://jpgraph.net/) jpgraph both look like the are free. There are many more if you do a search for php charts.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't. The code is run directly by the browser, so the user can see it, and the same for the data.

The slightly more complicated answer is that you could try to encrypt/obfuscate your data, but even then the user will be able to get to it with some effort, as the same comment I've made above still applies.

In short, if you don't want the user to see it, don't send it to the browser. You could, for example, generate visualisations as images on the server and have the browser download only the image.